# Checked and unchecked exceptions; what makes them different?

Tags: java, exception

I've been trying to get the hang of exceptions but I've run into some problems. I'm going to explain what I know and add **bold text** to the parts I'm not sure of:

I understand that there are Checked exceptions and Unchecked exceptions (**The latter are all subclasses of RuntimeException?**).

In methods where Checked exceptions can be thrown, the method signature NEEDS to state this (**At least if I've understood what I've read about exceptions correctly?**).
E.g.:

```
public void m() throws IOException{
...
}
```

This doesn't need to be done for Unchecked exceptions (**It doesn't NEED to, but CAN it**?)

I also know that you can "try" a piece of your code and any exceptions that might be thrown there will be caught in the "catch" part (Try-Catch). **Does this have to be done for both checked and unchecked exceptions? When do I have to do this?**

To clarify the second part of the last question, a class like

```
public class A
{
    private int[] items;

    public int first()
    {
        return items[0];
    }
}
```

Will return a NullPointerException. Yet there's no Try-Catch part, so when do I need to use Try-Catch and when don't I?

Thanks a lot in advance!

P.s. I've already read some answers regarding this topic on StackOverflow but none are really specific to the problems I'm experiencing.

Comment: You can deduce the answer to most of your questions by just analysing the results of running your code. `Does this have to be done for both checked and unchecked exceptions? When do I have to do this?` You got a `NullPointerException` but you didn't have a `try-catch` block. `(The latter are all subclasses of RuntimeException?` Check the parent class of `NullPointerException`. `It doesn't NEED to, but CAN it?` Try it.

Comment: 100% agreed. It's not these aren't good questions, it's just that they are easy to answer on your own by trying it.

Comment: Yes / Yes / Yes / No, only checked / It depends!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important thing to know about exceptions is that *you don't need to catch them*, at least not directly where they happen. This property of the exception sets it apart from the return value, and makes it a useful language feature to achieve execution flow patterns typically needed for error/exceptional event handling.

The only distracting thing about exceptions in Java are the checked exceptions, which induce a sort of urgency about handling them. Fact is, you don't have to handle a checked exception either, but  the complete call path leading from the exception to the handler must be beset with `throws` declarations. This ranges from very awkward to impossible. The standard workaround for that is catching the checked exception right away, only to throw another, unchecked one, which *wraps* the original.

Comment: What does this statement mean? `This property of the exception sets it apart from the return value` @markoTopolnik

Comment: My actual doubt was, in what context we can compare a return value with exceptions.. @marko

Comment: @MaheshVarma There are two ways a method can complete: with a return value or with an exception. Both of these are the *outcome* of a method.

Comment: It's unfortunate, IMHO, that the only way for a method which doesn't expect a nested method to throw a checked exception to avoid having to handle it is to add a `throws`; I would guess that the majority of the time when code doesn't want to handle a checked exception, it should really be caught and rethrown as an unchecked.  If Foo calls Bar and is expecting that Bar will never actually throw a certain exception, it's highly unlikely that the code which calls Foo will expect that such an exception might come from Bar.

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question:

> I also know that you can "try" a piece of your code and any exceptions that might be thrown there will be caught in the "catch" part (Try-Catch). Does this have to be done for both checked and unchecked exceptions? When do I have to do this?

The only time you *have* to do this (in order to make the program legal) is when a your method does something that could throw a *checked* exception, and you don't want to, or can't, list that exception in a `throws` clause.  (If you're writing a method that overrides a method in a parent class, and the method in the parent class doesn't list an exception in a `throws` clause, the overriding method in the subclass can't list it either.)  Then you have to handle it, by using `try`..`catch`.  If the Java compiler is convinced that any place the checked exception could be thrown, then it will be caught and handled by a `catch`, then the program is legal.  Otherwise it won't compile.

For unchecked exceptions, you never have to `catch` the exception to make the program compile.

Of course, you still "have" to `catch` an exception, even an unchecked one, if it's necessary for your program to behave the way you want.  (For example, if not catching the exception means an ugly stack trace appears on your web site and your customers get so freaked out that they never visit it any more.)  But I'm just talking about program legality.