# Should we handle unchecked exceptions in Java?

Tags: java, exception

I was asked in an interview:

> Is it good practice to handle unchecked exceptions with a try-catch block or should we leave them unhandled? Should we write most of our code between try-catch?

Looking for some satisfactory reason...

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checked and unchecked exceptions; what makes them different?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21239911/checked-and-unchecked-exceptions-what-makes-them-different)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a matter on which the person who is asking the question should show some minimal amount of effort.

Comment: I see some good and helpful discussion in this post's answers. In my opinion, this post **shouldn't** be marked as `closed`.

Answer (score 3):

It depends what the unchecked exception it is that we are referring to. In a lot of cases you can foresee that an unchecked exception may get thrown. A simple example where I regularly catch unchecked exceptions is the `NumberFormatException`. It is fine not to check this if you can be absolutely certain that when using `Integer.parseInt(String)` that the string will be a number but its probably very rare otherwise, why wouldn't it be stored as an `Integer` in the first place? You are probably taking a string which is input by a user and where this is the case, it may be worthwhile catching this to handle an invalid input in an appropriate way (like asking them to re-enter their input).

On the other hand, there are some unchecked exceptions which you should be able to avoid ever having to catch. An example of this would be the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Before trying to access part of an array, you should make sure that you know it is available. This is usually possible by checking the size of the array against the index you are trying to access. Allowing the exception to be thrown and then catching it as you way of 'checking' is inefficient as creating exceptions has an overhead.

With regards to wrapping all code in try-catch, I can't help but feel the implication that you have an expectation for the code to break when doing so and you should not be dealing with problems that you don't know the cause of. If you mean literally wrap your program in a `try {...} catch (Exception ex) {...}` I cant see any use for this as all you will be doing is what the JVM will do for you, when the exception gets thrown all the way down the stack. You could do some handling and maybe trying to recover, but try to recover what? If you are just catching `Exception`, you don't know what went wrong that needs recovering.

There may be some times where wrapping code in a large try-catch may be useful (if you don't want some small part of the system to end up breaking the whole thing) but in general, there is usually ways to avoid these things happening in the first place, or dealing with them better than just wrap it in a huge try-catch.

Answer (score 0):

You should handle exceptions, you have something useful to do with them. Hint catching them and continuing as if they didn't happen is not a good idea.

You also need to handle unchecked exceptions if you have to as the method doesn't declare a parent of that checked exception in it's `throws` clause

Comment: The OP is asking about the unchecked exceptions, not the checked exceptions.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad Re-worded to make clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that an exception is either checked or unchecked must not figure in your decision whether to handle it. The choice between the two was made by the writer of the method you are calling, and the decision whether to catch it is all yours.

You must inform yourself on the conditions in which the exception is thrown, and then you must decide what you want to do in those conditions.

Note that many APIs today are designed with *no checked exceptions whatsoever* and many of them are of the recoverable kind. This makes the checked/unchecked distinction even less substantial.